# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: table "freqs" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

In my db folder, I have two migrations that have do do with this. The first is a migration I created to drop a database I made earlier that did not have what I needed.

```
class DropProductsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :freqs
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

The second is the new database I created.

```
class CreateFreqs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :freqs do |t|
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The rake db:migrate works for development, but when I try to migrate Heroku, the error provided in the title occurs. What's happening? I have searched around StackOverflow to no avail.

Comment: Was there a stacktrace? Have you gone into psql to see if the table is there in Heroku?

Comment: I'm very new to Rails and working with databases. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can run `psql` in Heroku with `heroku pg:psql` per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli  Do you know enough SQL to check for the table once you're in psql?

Comment: According to Alex, the table does not exist in my database, and I must skip the first migration and migrate the second only.

Comment: That's probably true, but it's possible that the table is getting dropped as part of a transaction before you encounter the error and the drop is getting rolled back.  If the table doesn't exist, you also have to ask yourself why the table was created in development, but not in Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "to drop a database" - not database, but table you mean, right?
Then, it's obvious that this table doesn't exist on Heroku. Try to skip first migration and migrate only second.

Comment: Got it working by commenting out the contents of the up and down methods. Thanks, pal.